# How to represent a binary relation

Tags: optimization, data-structures, poset

I plan to make a class that represents a strict partially ordered set, and I assume the most natural way to model its interface is as a binary relation. This gives functions like:

```
bool test(elementA, elementB); //return true if elementA < elementB
void set(elementA, elementB); //declare that elementA < elementB
void clear(elementA, elementB); //forget that elementA < elementB
```

and possibly functions like:

```
void applyTransitivity(); //if test(a,b) and test(b, c), then set(a, c)
bool checkIrreflexivity(); //return true if for no a, a < a
bool checkAsymmetry(); //return true if for no a and b, a < b and b < a
```

The naive implementation would be to have a list of pairs such that (a, b) indicates a < b. However, it's probably not optimal. For example, `test` would be linear time. Perhaps it could be better done as a hash map of lists.

Ideally, though, the in memory representation would by its nature enforce `applyTransitivity` to always be "in effect" and not permit the creation of edges that cause reflexivity or symmetry. In other words, the degrees of freedom of the data structure represent the degrees of freedom of a strict poset. Is there a known way to do this? Or, more realistically, is there a means of checking for being cyclical, and maintaining transitivity that is amortized and iterative with each call to `set` and `clear`, so that the cost of enforcing the correctness is low. Is there a working implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's talk about achieving bare metal-scraping micro-efficiency, and you can choose how deep down that abyss you want to go. At this architectural level, there are no data structures like hash maps and lists, there aren't even data types, just bits and bytes in memory.

*As an aside, you'll also find a lot of info on representations here by looking into common representations of DAGs. However, most of the common reps are designed more for convenience than efficiency.*

Here, we want the data for `a` to be fused with that adjacency data into a single memory block. So you want to store the 'list', so to speak, of items that have a relation to `a` in `a's` own memory block so that we can potentially access `a` and all the elements related to `a` within a single cache line (bonus points if those related elements might also fit in the same cache line, but that's an NP-hard problem).

You can do that by storing, say, 32-bit indices in `a`. We can model such objects like so if we go a little higher level and use C for exemplary purposes:

```
struct Node
{
    // node data
    ...
    int links[]; // variable-length struct
};
```

This makes the `Node` a variable-length structure whose size and potentially even address changes, so we need an extra level of indirection to get stability and avoid invalidation, like an index to an index (if you control the memory allocator/array and it's purely contiguous), or an index to a pointer (or reference in some languages).

That makes your test function still involve a linear time search, but linear with respect to the number of elements related to `a`, not the number of elements total. Because we used a variable-length structure, `a` and its neighbor indices will potentially fit in a single cache line, and it's likely that `a` will already be in the cache just to make the query.

It's similar to the basic idea you had of the hash map storing lists, but without the explosion of lists overhead and without the hash lookup (which may be constant time but not nearly as fast as just accessing the connections to `a` from the same memory block). Most importantly, it's far more cache-friendly, and that's often going to make the difference between a few cycles and hundreds.

Now this means that you still have to roll up your sleeves and check for things like cycles yourself. If you want a data structure that more directly and conveniently models the problem, you'll find a nicer fit with graph data structures revolving around a formalization of a directed edge. However, those are much more convenient than they are efficient.

If you need the container to be generic and `a` can be any given type, T, then you can always wrap it (using C++ now):

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T node_data;
    int links[1]; // VLS, not necessarily actually storing 1 element
};
```

And still fuse this all into one memory block this way. We need placement new here to preserve those C++ object semantics and possibly keep an eye on alignment here.

Transitivity checks always involves a search of some sort (breadth first or depth first). I don't think there's any rep that avoids this unless you want to memoize/cache a potentially massive explosion of transitive data.

At this point you should have something pretty fast if you want to go this deep down the abyss and have a solution that's really hard to maintain and understand. I've unfortunately found that this doesn't impress the ladies very much as with the case of having a car that goes really fast, but it can make your software go really, really fast.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping things low level for a cache performance boost. I expect reads to be significantly more common than writes, so I think I'll also add binary search into the mix for that extra oomph.